# How to show the Font Awesome icons

Tags: html, css

I added Font Awesome icons inside the `<span>` tags and also added the style of font awesome in my CSS page. But the icon was not displayed correctly. I need to show the icons correctly.

I have added the font awesome in the HTML as `<span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#61447";> </span>` but it doesn't work.

HTML markup:

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" >
    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#61447";> </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.focus-input100 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.focus-input100::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;

  background: #fff;
}

.focus-input100::after {
  font-family: Material-Design-Iconic-Font;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;

  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.input100:focus {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.input100:focus + .focus-input100::after {
  top: -22px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.input100:focus + .focus-input100::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.has-val.input100 + .focus-input100::after {
  top: -22px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.has-val.input100 + .focus-input100::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.has-val.input100 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Using my code the icon are view as a small rectangle box but I need the correct image of the icon I have used.

Use this link to see my problem:  http://enreachapp.com/login/login2.php

Answer (score 0):

First in provide code you are not using `Font Awesome` you are using `material icon`.

On based on that you have to update you `font-family` and `content`. replace below code with your css and check you will get the icon.

I have added home icon for you others you have to add it as per your requirement depend on code.

```css
.focus-input100 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.focus-input100::before {
  content: "";
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  background: #fff;
}

.focus-input100::after {
  font-family: Material-Design-Iconic-Font;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
  content: "\f175";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.input100:focus {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.input100:focus+.focus-input100::after {
  top: -22px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.input100:focus+.focus-input100::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.has-val.input100+.focus-input100::after {
  top: -22px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.has-val.input100+.focus-input100::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.has-val.input100 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}



.focus-input101 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.focus-input101::before {
  content: "";
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  background: #fff;
}

.focus-input101::after {
  font-family: Material-Design-Iconic-Font;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
  content: "\f18f";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.input101:focus {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.input101:focus+.focus-input101::after {
  top: -22px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.input101:focus+.focus-input101::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.has-val.input101+.focus-input101::after {
  top: -22px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.has-val.input101+.focus-input101::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.has-val.input101 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">

<span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">Log in</span>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter username"><input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#61447;"></span></div>

<div class="wrap-input101 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
<input class="input101" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="password"><span class="focus-input101" data-placeholder="&#61475;"></span></div>
```

Comment: i need the home and lock  images

Comment: and also need a eye image in the right side of the password filed

Comment: I have added a home icon for you please check snippet plan similar for all other icon.

Comment: my HTML CODE :
 <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">Log in</span>
     <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username"><input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ><span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#61447;"></span></div>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password"><input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="password"  ><span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#61475;"></span></div>this display both home icon

Comment: i need to add the eye icon in the right side of the input filed please help me

Comment: i did 2 icons for you now you have to deal with other one. StackOverflow is for helping you where you stuck  not for the writing your code.